# Fast splash screen like instagram

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to do a splashscreen in my app like instagram. But after 2 packages i can't reproduce it so clean.

Cuttenly using splashscreen package like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 1,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
      title: Text('Welcome In SplashScreen',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20.0
        ),
      ),
      image: Image.asset("assets/logo_launcher.png"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      styleTextUnderTheLoader: TextStyle(),
      photoSize: 100.0,
      loaderColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm oppening the app, it takes 3~5 seconds to load the splashscreen.
It's possible to replicate the instagram one? Clicking on instagram, opens splashscreen instantaneously and does not stay "3~5 seconds in a blank page"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to show is the native splash. You may use this package : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash or there are several articles that explain different ways you can implement native splash. You may also want to look at a very recent article : https://twitter.com/Nikkitagandhi/status/1321313796091097088

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and configure a launch screen. More info at:

Adding a splash screen to your mobile app
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen

and

Apple Human Interface Guidelines : Launch Screen
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/